# would + should in one sentence

Tags: should, would

*If the classic authorities could be wrong about so many things, why **would should** they be trusted about anything?*

It is from the article in Atlantic https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2016/11/progress-isnt-natural-mokyr/507740/

Is it grammatically correct? Does it seem weird to the native speaker?

Comment: Likely an editor's oversight.

Comment: Perhaps " would/should" is intended or it's a typo!

Comment: I find at least one typo in the 1st section of the NY Times on a weekly basis. It happens – editors are only human. On the other hand, I've never found a single typo in the New Yorker magazine after 40 years of reading. They're either inhuman, or just extraordinarily precise.

Comment: @IconDaemon This is the New Yorker you’re talking about:  surely they coöpt the entire editorial team to carefully reëxamine each and every jot and tittle.

Comment: @tchrist It's 2017, what editorial team? Do you mean that one harried guy who's 27 but looks like he's 103?

Comment: @tchrist - I up-voted your comment for the use of umlauts, which the New Yorker uses in abundance where appropriate.

Comment: Looks like a cut&paste error, in which you insert two versions for comparison and wham-bam forget to delete one. Oy.